# Intermittent wifi connection issues even when right next to router (Linksys EA4500)

Tags: wireless-networking, internet-connection

I have a cable modem connected to a Linksys EA4500.  We bought it to replace an aging router in hopes of it giving a better range in our apartment.  The cable/router is in the front of the apartment and we have an office and TV in the bedroom at the back of the apartment.  It's only about 80', but there are a bunch of walls in the way.  The output from the router was less than impressive, so we bought a range extender, a Netgear WN2500RP, to hopefully bridge the gap.

Now we appear to be having intermittent issues with connecting to the Linksys router.  I have a Raspberry Pi with a USB wifi stick and it can't connect at all, and I have two Macbook Pros (one an older 2011, and one a brand new Retina) that have trouble connecting.  I can usually get it connected, but after finagling with it anywhere from a minute to half an hour.  I turn wifi on/off, remove remembered networks, etc. and it'll usually eventually connect.

Because it usually connects, I haven't done any exhaustive investigation on this yet - I'm really just hoping to soon replace this router as it's been nothing but trouble. But here's the weird thing, and the reason I'm writing it up here.  On the Netgear extender, it sets separate network names for the 2.4 and 5Ghz bands.  When trying to connect to wifi, if I can see all three networks I can usually connect without an issue.  But sometimes I can only see the Linksys (wired) network and the extender's 2.4GHz band.  In that case, I can't connect, even when I'm sitting just a few feet from the Linksys router.

One other caveat here - my neighborhood used to have 5-10 networks in range, but lately that's climbed up to over 30. I've tried looking into network interference and changing channels, but I'm still having trouble with the initial connection - once connected everything is fine, usually no video buffering or disconnects, etc. and good download speeds.

Comment: I've voted to move this over to Superuser, where they deal better with consumer-level gear. Serverfault is for professional environments. Good luck!

Comment: If this gets moved, I will try to help out.  But in the meantime, have you checked the channel saturation?  A simple wifi app can do this from a mobile device.  Basically you might be fighting for bandwidth with other wifi networks..

Comment: Ok, wasn't sure of the best place to put this, so please move to serverfault if that makes better sense.  I believe saturation could be at least part of it - I've used 'wifi explorer' to see what channels to use and have switched them up with some little success, but my apartment is now so saturated on the 2.4Ghz band that it's difficult to find a good channel.  The 5Ghz band is a bit better, with only a handful of other networks using it right now.